# how to implement natural sort in common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I tried to implement a natural sort:

```
Break 21 [92]> (defparameter *sss* '("1.txt" "10.txt" "13.txt" "12.txt" "2.txt" "23.txt"))
*SSS*
Break 21 [92]> (sort *sss* #'string-lessp)
("1.txt" "10.txt" "12.txt" "13.txt" "2.txt" "23.txt")
Break 21 [92]>
```

Unfortunately, the code above does not work.

Could someone help me to get a natural sort function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, the code above does not work.

It looks like it worked.  After all, you explicitly asked to sort by *string comparison*, and according to a string comparison, `"2.txt"` is between `"13.txt"`, and `"23.txt"`.  If you want to sort numerically, you could use a key function that would read the number from the beginning of the string.  Also, **sort** is destructive, so you shouldn't use it on literal data (like a quoted list).

At any rate, it's not too hard to cobble together something that will get you the sort of sorting that you're looking for. Here's a definition for a **natural-string-lessp** function:

```
(defun natural-string-lessp (a b)
  (multiple-value-bind (ai aend)
      (parse-integer a :junk-allowed t)
    (multiple-value-bind (bi bend)
        (parse-integer b :junk-allowed t)
      (or (and ai
               (or (not bi)
                   (and bi
                        (or (< ai bi)
                            (and (= ai bi)
                                 (string-lessp a b :start1 aend :start2 bend))))))
          (and (not ai)
               (not bi)
               (string-lessp a b))))))
```

It only handles the leading numbers, and not numbers in the middle of a string, so, e.g., `"a-100-foo.txt"` will still come before `"a-3-foo.txt"`, but it might be sufficient for your needs.  Here's an example of its use:

```
(let ((sss (copy-list '("1.txt" "10.txt" "13.txt" "12.txt"
                        "2.txt" "23.txt"))))
  (sort sss #'natural-string-lessp))
;=> ("1.txt" "2.txt" "10.txt" "12.txt" "13.txt" "23.txt")
```

The documentation for [**parse-integer**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_parse_.htm) and the keyword arguments for [**string-lessp**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stgeq_.htm) may be helpful.

A more robust implementation would figure out how to turn each string into a sequence of strings and numbers, (e.g., `"12.txt"` → `(12 ".txt")`) and then sort those lists lexicographically with an ordering among types (e.g., numbers before strings), and with an ordering within each type.

Comment: Here is a version I once wrote: https://gist.github.com/lispm/e028d3f3c11c9f74d4e7

Comment: Btw, when we use literal data in a REPL, it should be most of the time okay. The REPL usually creates new fresh data. Would you see a problem in REPL use?

Comment: If you evaluate `(defun foo () (sort '(1 2 3) '<))` in SBCL, you'll get eleven lines warning about the destructive modification of literal data.  Since you get the behavior you'd expect, it's probably not quite so big a deal in the REPL, but good habits with little can lead to good habits with much.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a general `string-natural-lessp`:

```
(defun string-natural-lessp (string-a string-b
                             &key
                               (start-a 0)
                               (end-a (length string-a))
                               (start-b 0)
                               (end-b (length string-b)))
  (do ((a-index start-a)
       (b-index start-b))
      ((or (>= a-index end-a)
           (>= b-index end-b))
       (not (>= b-index end-b)))
    (multiple-value-bind (a-int a-pos)
        (parse-integer string-a
                       :start a-index
                       :junk-allowed t)
      (multiple-value-bind (b-int b-pos)
          (parse-integer string-b
                         :start b-index
                         :junk-allowed t)
        (if (and a-int b-int)
            (if (= a-int b-int)
                (setf a-index a-pos
                      b-index b-pos)
                (return-from string-natural-lessp (< a-int b-int)))
            (if (char-equal (aref string-a a-index)
                            (aref string-b b-index))
                (progn
                  (incf a-index)
                  (incf b-index))
                (return-from string-natural-lessp
                  (char-lessp (aref string-a a-index)
                              (aref string-b b-index)))))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the use case, I guess. I'd try something like

```
(defun natural-compare (a b)
  (labels ((int (str) (parse-integer str :junk-allowed t)))
    (let ((n-a (int a))
          (n-b (int b)))
      (if (and n-a n-b (/= n-a n-b))
          (<= n-a n-b)
          (string<= a b)))))

(defun natural-sort (strings)
  (sort (copy-list strings) #'natural-compare))
```

It works:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *sss* '("1.txt" "test.txt" "36-test.txt" "36-taste.txt" "sicp.pdf" "answers.txt" "10.txt" "13.txt" "12.txt" "2.txt" "23.txt"))
*SSS*
CL-USER> (natural-sort *sss*)
("1.txt" "2.txt" "10.txt" "12.txt" "13.txt" "23.txt" "36-taste.txt"
 "36-test.txt" "answers.txt" "sicp.pdf" "test.txt")
CL-USER>
```

but does a bit more work than it really needs to. Note that `natural-sort` copies the input list because `sort` is a destructive procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Generate a proper sorting key for every element and then use those for comparison:

```
(defun skip-zeros (string offset length)
  (do ((i offset (1+ i)))
      ((or (>= i length)
           (not (eql (aref string i) #\0)))
       i)))

(defun skip-digits (string offset length)
  (do ((i offset (1+ i)))
      ((or (>= i length)
           (not (digit-char-p (aref string i))))
       i)))

(defun skip-alphas (string offset length)
  (do ((i offset (1+ i)))
      ((or (>= i length)
           (not (alpha-char-p (aref string i))))
       i)))

(defun make-natural-sorting-key (string)
  (let* ((length (length string))
         (key (make-array (+ length 5)
                          :element-type 'character
                          :fill-pointer 0
                          :adjustable t))
        (offset 0))
    (do ()
        ((>= offset length) (coerce key 'simple-string))
      (block eater
        (let ((c (aref string offset))
              (end))
          (cond
            ((digit-char-p c) (setf offset (skip-zeros string offset length))
                              (setf end (skip-digits string offset length))
                              (do ((digits (- end offset) (- digits 9)))
                                  ((< digits 9) (vector-push-extend (digit-char digits) key))
                                (vector-push-extend #\9 key)))
            ((alpha-char-p c) (setf end (skip-alphas string offset length)))
            (t (incf offset)
               (return-from eater)))
          (do ((i offset (1+ i)))
              ((>= i end))
            (vector-push-extend (aref string i) key))
          (vector-push-extend #\nul key)
          (setf offset end))))))


(sort data #'string< :key #'make-natural-sorting-key)
```

Though, ensure that your sort implementation caches the keys.